# RegEx for matching and replacing punctuations, numbers and special chars

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am looking for a regular expression which written in python to remove punctuation , numbers and symbols (like $ - . , @ etc) from a text and convert the text in the lower case as well.

Sample Text is:

```
I'm looking for text without the given numbers like 123, $223.423 ab-c@cde. Is it possible with the python regular expression?
```

Output Text is:

```
i looking for text without the given numbers like is it possible with the python regular expression
```

Comment: I had tried it with several separate things but I didn't able to do it with a single regular expression. re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation)), lower(string), replace() and string.isalpha(). Please help me if it possible with a single regular expression

Answer (score 0):

```py
ss = "I'm looking for text without the given numbers like 123, $223.423 ab-c@cde. Is it possible with the python regular expression?"
ss1 = ''.join([i for i in ss if i.isalpha() or i == " "]).replace("   "," ").lower()
print(ss1)
```

output:

```
im looking for text without the given numbers like abccde is it possible with the python regular expression
```

enjoy